# django-why this form is always invalid

Tags: python, django, django-forms

i have created a form with minimal fields(for testing) , but it never enters **form.is_valid()**

Here is the minimal code

in the **models.py**

```
 from django.db import models

 class sample(models.Model):
      field1=models.CharField(max_length=100)
      field2=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

in the forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from app.models import sample

class someform(ModelForm):
      class Meta:
        model=sample
```

in the views.py

```
some imports

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'app/index.html')

def contact(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
         form=someform(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
            field1=form.cleaned_data['field1']
            field2=form.cleaned_data['field2']
            return HttpResponse("valid")
         else:
            return HttpResponse("invalid")
    else:
            form=someform()
            return HttpResponse("error")
```

The problem is , it never enters (if form.is_valid()) . Am i missing something ? please help

in the index.html

```
<html>
      <body bgcolor="#2E9AFE">
      <form action="contact" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="text" id="field1" name="field1">
      <input type="text" id="field2" name="field2">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
      </form></body></html>
```

Comment: Could we see your template where the form is rendered ?

Comment: sorry...i edited the question with the templates

Answer (score 4):

First pass your form to index.html, when the request is not POST in views.py:

```
else:
            form=someform()
            return render(request, 'index.html', locals())
```

In template you should make it like this:

```
<form action="contact" method="POST" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

When receiving the POST query, Django is looking for the 2 fields of IDs `id_field1` and `id_field2`, litteraly, thus your HTML is to be the following:

```
<html>
   <body bgcolor="#2E9AFE">
      <form action="contact" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
         <input type="text" id="id_field1" name="field1">
         <input type="text" id="id_field2" name="field2">
         <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit">
         </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

Another solution is to use the `{{ form.as_p }}` or `{{ form.as_table }}` to render the inputs inside

or  tags automatically.

You could also add `{{ form.non_field_errors }}`, `{{ form.field1.errors }}`, and `{{ form.field2.errors }}` in your current HTML to display the form errors when validation fails.

Comment: thanx sir , i have added id_ thing as prefix in the ids part , i am confused in the flow , what is the flow ... acc to me first index.html is rendered , user fills field1 and field2 , now in the views i can collect these values by using form.cleaned_data[] as i have done above in the question .... if form is validated , values will be collected .....is that the flow..... or i messed up the concepts?

Comment: __form.is_valid()__ collects the POST data and populates the form errors (field errors and non-fields errors) and the cleaned_data dictionary. Then if the form is valid, cleaned_data contains all the fields without __required=False__, and may contain some fields with __required=False__ if they are not null/false. If the form is invalid, you can return it to the template, and use the 5 tags I gave you to display the Django validation errors. Best is using __form.as_p__ or __form.as_table__ to render it in the template easily.